# Excel looping from column A and finding matches with corresponding values and moving them to a new worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

Excel looping from column A and finding matches with corresponding values and moving them to a new worksheet.

Fairly new to excel VBA.  Having trouble creating a loop for finding matching drug names with corresponding values in a worksheet when compared to drugs in column A. The matches to column A would be reported in order on a second worksheet.

**Intention:**

Raw data - Drugs (column A) with corresponding values (scores in column B) from one cell line are listed.  Then in column C and D, drugs and corresponding values, respectively, from another cell line are listed.  This can go on and on depending on how many cell lines are tested. The key is that not all cell lines are treated with all the same drugs.  We are trying to only sort the matching drugs with corresponding values. We will then be able to compare how drugs work across cell lines.

See the included figure for an example of the data sets. The headers for the cell line (Row 1) and Drug and Score (Row 2) take up the first 2 rows.

Starting with the first drug in column A, Range (“A3”) in my example, you would look from matches in column C, E, G, etc, depending on how many cell lines are analyzed. If a match is found, the drug with its corresponding data is then placed on a “Sorted” worksheet.  If for example 3 cell lines with data were reported, the original drug name and data from Cell line A would be placed on Range(“A3, B3”), the matches from Cell line B would be placed next to the original in the order Range(“C3,D3”), and the matches from cell line 3 would be placed on Range(“E3,F3”).

We have drug and response (scores) data from many cell lines, but not all the drugs were tested in every cell line.  We want to find the common drugs that were tested in all the cell lines.

I was able to write a macro (see below) to find a match in the first compared column (C) and report the row value, but I was stuck after that when I tried to consider how to extract that name and corresponding value and move it to the sorted worksheet.  I know all the general language for copy, paste, offset, looping, but when I start working with Dim’s I get lost on how to extract those findings.

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks in advance!

[Drug and score table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8TY1C.jpg)

```
Sub Find_matching_drug()

    'Declaring variables. will start with first _
    drug in column A3, then move to A4, A5, etc _
    matches with corresponding values will be sent _
    to a different worksheet

    Dim i As Integer, drug_to_find As String

    'drug_to_find (variable) is defined as A3

    drug_to_find = Range("A3").Value

    MsgBox drug_to_find

    For i = 1 To 500  ' searches column up to 500 rows for the match
        If Cells(i, 3).Value = drug_to_find Then

            MsgBox ("Found value on row " & i)
            Exit Sub
        End If
    Next i

    ' This MsgBox will only show if the loop completes with no success
    MsgBox ("Value not found in the range!")
End Sub
```

Comment: This would be pretty straightforward if you could re-organize your data such that there's only a single column of results, with a new "cell line" column to capture the cell line associated with that result.  Then you could create a pivot table based off that.

Comment: Am I understanding this correctly - columns A, C, E, etc of the result sheet will have the same values (drug names) per row (although some may be blanks) and columns B, D, F, etc of the result sheet will have the equivalent of a VLOOKUP using the value in the previous column as the value to be found and the search range being the equivalent columns in the source data.  So all you are wanting to do is line things up so that each drug (and their corresponding scores) is on the same row in each cell line.

Comment: Thanks for the rapid replies and effort!  YowE3K - your code worked beautifully.  Thanks!  Tim - I agree that your method of organizing the data would be more efficient. Just to make sure I understand, column A would list the names of the cell lines, and column B would be the scores? Here is an example

Comment: Example: column A - Cell line A ganetesib, column B - 98. You would then just change Cell line A to Cell line B ganetesib when you get to the next set of data.

Answer (score 0):

If my understanding (see comment to question) is correct, the following code should (hopefully? maybe?) work:

```
Sub Q40986052()
    Dim src As Worksheet
    Dim dst As Worksheet
    Dim c As Long
    Dim dstrow As Long
    Dim numcols As Long

    Set src = Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Set dst = Worksheets("Sheet2")

    'copy headings
    numcols = src.Cells(2, src.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    src.Range(src.Cells(1, 1), src.Cells(2, numcols)).Copy dst.Range("B1")

    'create a list of all drugs
    dstrow = 3
    For c = 1 To numcols Step 2
        src.Range(src.Cells(3, c), src.Cells(src.Rows.Count, c).End(xlUp)).Copy dst.Cells(dstrow, 1)
        dstrow = dst.Cells(dst.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1
    Next

    'remove duplicate entries
    dst.Range(dst.Cells(3, 1), dst.Cells(dstrow - 1, 1)).RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlNo
    dstrow = dst.Cells(dst.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1

    'create vlookups
    For c = 1 To numcols Step 2
        dst.Range(dst.Cells(3, c + 1), dst.Cells(dstrow, c + 1)).FormulaR1C1 = "=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(RC1,'" & src.Name & "'!C[-1]:C,1,FALSE),"""")"
        dst.Range(dst.Cells(3, c + 2), dst.Cells(dstrow, c + 2)).FormulaR1C1 = "=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(RC1,'" & src.Name & "'!C[-2]:C[-1],2,FALSE),"""")"
    Next

    'Calculate
    dst.Calculate

    'Convert to values
    dst.Range(dst.Cells(3, 2), dst.Cells(dstrow, numcols + 1)).Value = dst.Range(dst.Cells(3, 2), dst.Cells(dstrow, numcols + 1)).Value

    'remove temporary column
    dst.Cells(1, 1).EntireColumn.Delete

End Sub
```